# Uninstalling Office 2010 breaks software, Reinstalling it fixes it

Tags: vb6, ms-office

I have an application written in VB6 that uses JET OLEDB 4.0 drivers.  On all of our workstations that have this software installed, Office 2010 was uninstalled and replaced with Office 2016.  This caused the software to stop working and give a vague Out of Memory error.  After re-installing Office 2010 on one of the workstations, the software started working again.  I tried installing the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 redistributable prior to reinstalling Office 2010, but this had no affect.  Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening ?

Comment: The Jet 4.0 OLEDB Provider is not a "driver."  You may be confusing it with ODBC technology, where they use the term "driver" as a sort of synonym for "plug in."  In any case that Provider is a preinstalled and protected part of the OS, so no amount of MS Office gymnastics should really mess with it.  Something else must really be going on.  Is it possible you are thunking into ODBC via the MSDASQL shim Provider?

Comment: I am definitely using JET OLEDB 4.0 Provider in the connection string.  I apologize for the incorrect nomenclature.

Comment: Are you using internal-VBA functions and methods in your queries?

Comment: No, just simply connecting to a database using the provider.

Comment: [This thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?818083-VB6-application-not-connecting-to-Access-database-2016-in-windows-10) may be of some help.